# BioConductor IRanges coverage counts and identify segments

Tags: r

I have a dataset with interval information for a bunch of manufacturing circuits

```
df <- data.frame(structure(list(circuit = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), start = structure(c(1393621200, 
1393627920, 1393628400, 1393631520, 1393650300, 1393646400, 1393656000, 
1393668000, 1393666200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
end = structure(c(1393626600, 1393631519, 1393639200, 1393632000, 
1393660500, 1393673400, 1393667999, 1393671600, 1393677000
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), id = structure(1:9, .Label = c("1001", 
"1002", "1003", "1004", "1005", "1006", "1007", "1008", "1009"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("circuit", "start", "end", 
"id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L)))
```

[image]

- **Circuit**: Identifier for circuit
- **Start**:  Time the circuit started running
- **Finish**: Time the circuit stopped running
- **Id**: Unique identifier for the row

I'm able to create a new data set that counts the number of overlapping intervals:

```
ir <- IRanges(start = as.numeric(df$start), end = as.numeric(df$end), names = df$id)

cov <- coverage(ir)

start_time <- as.POSIXlt(start(cov), origin = "1970-01-01")
end_time   <- as.POSIXlt(end(cov), origin = "1970-01-01")
seconds    <- runLength(cov)
circuits_running <- runValue(cov)

res <- data.frame(start_time,end_time,seconds,circuits_running)[-1,]
```

[image]

But what I really need is something that looks more like this:

```
sqldf("select 
            res.start_time, 
            res.end_time, 
            res.seconds, 
            res.circuits_running, 
            df.circuit, 
            df.id
      from res left join df on (res.start_time between df.start and df.end)")
```

[image]

The problem is that the `sqldf` way of using an inequality join is unbearably slow on my full dataset.

**How can I get something similar using `IRanges` alone?**

I suspect it has something to do with `RangedData` but I've not been able to see how to get what I want. Here's what I've tried...

```
rd <- RangedData(ir, circuit = df$circuit, id = df$id)
coverage(rd) # works but seems to lose the circuit/id info
```

Comment: That's funny... I was asked something like this for my Google interview and the optimal answer ended up being a clever use of a max heap for a total of `O(n ln c)` runtime (where `n` is the number of records and `c` is the maximum # of simultaneous running circuits).

Comment: If its slow add indices to your query.  See sqldf home page for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coverage can be represented as ranges, dropping the first (the range from 1970 to the first start point)

```
cov <- coverage(ir)
intervals <- ranges(cov)[-1]
```

Your query is to find the start of the interval of each circuit, so I narrow the interval to their start coordinate and find overlaps (the first argument is the 'query', the second the 'subject')

```
olaps <- findOverlaps(narrow(intervals, width(intervals)), ir)
```

The number of circuits running in a particular interval is

```
tabulate(queryHits(olaps), queryLength(olaps))
```

and the actual circuits are

```
df[subjectHits(olaps), c("circuit", "id")]
```

The pieces can be knit together as, perhaps

```
df1 <- cbind(uid=seq_along(intervals),
             as.data.frame(intervals),
             circuits_running=tabulate(queryHits(olaps), queryLength(olaps)))
df2 <- cbind(uid=queryHits(olaps),
             df[subjectHits(olaps), c("circuit", "id")])
merge(df1, df2, by="uid", all=TRUE)
```

Ranges can have associated with them 'metadata' that is accessible and subset in a coordinated way, so the connection between data.frame and ranges does not have to be so loose and ad hoc. I might instead have

```
ir <- IRanges(start = as.numeric(df$start), end = as.numeric(df$end))
mcols(ir) <- DataFrame(df)
## ...
mcols(ir[subjectHits(olaps)])
```

perhaps with `as.data.frame()` when done with IRanges-land.

It's better to ask your questions about IRanges on the Bioconductor [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/); no subscription required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin - knitting everything together using the method you've outlined worked perfectly.